# Multiple dialects of languages in Django-CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

all, I'm attempting to create a multi-lingual website which must support (among others) both US-English and UK-English.

My settings contains:

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('de', u'Deutsch'),
    ('en_GB', u'English (UK)'),
    ('en', u'English (US)'),
    ('es', u'Español'),
    ('fr', u'Français'),
    ('pt', u'Português'),
)
```

All of the other languages are all working fine; the user can switch languages and things work well.  The problem is en_GB.

I've tried changing the above configuration to 'en-GB', 'en-gb or 'en_gb' with no change in behavior.

It would appear that the middleware only supports the first two letters for language pathing?  How can I properly support multiple dialects of the base language?  This could easily be es-US, es-MX, es-ES or fr-FR, fr-CA or de-DE, de-AT, de-CH, etc.

I'm using Django-CMS 2.3.5 (which is the latest production release as of this writing) on Django 1.4.5 on Python 2.7.2.

UPDATE: I appear to now have it working.  I think there were two things that were preventing progress for me.  1) when it comes to English, it is probably best to not have one as 'en' and another as 'en-gb'. 2) in all my experimenting, I suspect I had messed up Django-CMS' records in the DB.  Deleting all my pages and starting over seems to have fixed this (NOTE: This would suck in a production environment even more than it does here!)

In the end, I've found these settings to work for me:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en-us', u'English (US)'),
    ('de', u'Deutsch'),
    ('en-gb', u'English (UK)'),
    ('es', u'Español'),
    ('fr', u'Français'),
    ('pt', u'Português'),
)

CMS_LANGUAGES = LANGUAGES

CMS_LANGUAGE_CONF = {
    'de': ['en-gb', 'en-us', 'fr', 'es', 'pt'],
    'en-gb': ['en-us', 'fr', 'es', 'de', 'pt'],
    'en-us': ['en-gb', 'fr', 'es', 'de', 'pt'],
    'es': ['pt', 'fr', 'en-gb', 'en-us', 'de'],
    'fr': ['es', 'pt', 'en-gb', 'en-us', 'de'],
    'pt': ['es', 'fr', 'en-gb', 'en-us', 'de'],
}

CMS_HIDE_UNTRANSLATED = False
```

Also, apparently Django-CMS' template tag page_language_url will only return lower-case language path elements, so en_GB/en-GB may work on one level, but the UI will fail to match the selected language because of this.

Comment: @catherine "I've tried changing the above configuration to 'en-GB', 'en-gb or 'en_gb' with no change in behavior."

Comment: Huh? You'd like me to use ('cy', u'English (UK)')?  I'm not interested in Welsh-GB, but a UK dialect of English as opposed to the American dialect. (As a British-American myself, I DO know how silly that may sound)

Answer (score 3):

[Django I18N Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/) explain two codes as shown below. **en_GB** is the **Great Britain (UK)** *locale*. **en-CA** is *English as spoken in Canada*.

1. **locale name** has an *underscore*
2. **language_name** has a *dash* or *hyphen*

Comment: Interesting nuance between language and locale.  I've been wondering why the variations, this make much better sense now that I know this.

Answer (score 0):

## I think it's sequence issue, Languages must be above the language_code. could you please try this below.

```
LANGUAGES = (
        ('en-us', u'English (US)'),
        ('de', u'Deutsch'),
        ('en-gb', u'English (UK)'),
        ('es', u'Español'),
        ('fr', u'Français'),
        ('pt', u'Português'),
    )    

 LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
```

Comment: Sorry, I posted that over 4 years ago. I'm not working on that project any longer =) But hopefully, someone else will benefit from your answer.